# EMI Input filter

Tags: power, ac, filter, emc, conversion

I am looking at using a Cincon PDF700 AC-DC converter in one of my designs. In the datasheet it shows the EMI filter as having first a 30 mH common mode choke and then a 3 mH common mode choke using 2.2 µF capacitors.

I am having trouble sourcing a 30 mH common mode choke off the shelf which is ideally what I would like instead of having to wind my own. I have wound my own but there seems to be a faint buzzing from it. I have tried adhesive on the coils but the buzzing still exists so I'm not sure what the problem is.It sounds almost like a crackling noise. I have wound both coils about as perfect as I can see them ever being.

All similar modules use two 6 mH inductors and a 1 µF capacitor. Would it be okay to use a filter from a different module which uses the same frequency of 220kHz for the output stage however cincon doesn't list the switching frequency of the PFC stage.

The datasheet for the module I am using is here:

https://www.cincon.com/productdownload/PDF700S-series-application-note.pdf

And the similar design is here:

https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/power/switching-power/ac-dc-converter/specification/pfe700sa_spc.pdf

Comment: Please link the data sheet you mention. Add the link to your question.

Comment: If you can't compare PFC switching frequencies then you are in the dark.

Comment: Do you think the 30mh inductance is correct in the datasheet? It seems to be the converter that doesn't use the same for both the first and second stage. I have tried to contact cincon but haven't heard back.